# Is the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file enough to create and update files or is the scope /drive needed?

Tags: google-drive-api

Currently we only have the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly but we want to be able to write and update files to google drive as well. Reading the documentation they state that https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file is enough to create and update files. But before we apply to this I want to make sure this scope is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the Documentation  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` will only allow you access to files created or opened by the app(you).

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` allows you to access all of a user's files, excluding the Application Data folder.

So if you want to access all the user files `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` else `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is enough to create and update the files.

Comment: hello, I am not very clear with how to define this 'opened'. If the user created a doc on GoogleDrive webpage, is there a way to open it on my app first and then only use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to change permission?